# d3.js how to add rect only when it is not already added

Tags: d3.js

I am adding rect and text in to svg. However i would like to add only when it is empty. It should not be added multiple times.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<style></style>

<header>
</header>

<h1>Legends Data</h1>

<p id="legend"></p>

<input type="submit" value="Generatelegend" onclick=CreateLegend();>

<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js?2.8.1"></script>

<script>

   function CreateLegend()
{

   var margin = {top: 29.5, right: 29.5, bottom: 29.5, left: 59.5},
    width = 460 - margin.right,
    height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


    //Create the SVG for legends.
    var svglegend = d3.select("#legend").append("svg").attr("id","svglegend")
    .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

      //check svg exists



    // Create the SVG container and set the origin.
    var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");



    d3.json("SbuLegendData.json", function(data) {

    jsondata = data;


       //CreateLegend('legend', svglegend);
        rectangle= svglegend.selectAll("rect").data(data).enter().append("rect");
      var RectangleAttrb = rectangle.attr("x", function (d) { return d.x_axis; })
                       .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y_axis; })
                       .attr("width",function(d) { return d.width; } )
                   .attr("height",function(d) { return d.height; })
                       .style("fill", function(d) { return d.color; });




     var textparam = svglegend.selectAll("text").data(data).enter().append("text");

        var text = textparam .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x_axis + d.width +10; })
                       .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y_axis + d.height-5; })
                       .attr("width",30 )
                   .attr("height",20)
                       .text(function(d) { return d.text; });


    });
}

</script>
```

now in this function it keeps on adding the rect and text whenever the function gets called.

```
[
   { "x_axis":40, "y_axis": 10,"width":50,"height":20,"color" : "#1f77b4","text":"F&R"},
   { "x_axis":40, "y_axis": 30,"width":50,"height":20,"color" : "#ff7f0e","text":"Legal"},
   { "x_axis":40, "y_axis": 50,"width":50,"height":20,"color" : "#2ca02c","text":"GGO"},
   { "x_axis":40, "y_axis": 70,"width":50,"height":20,"color" : "#d62728","text":"IP&S"},
   { "x_axis":40, "y_axis": 90,"width":50,"height":20,"color" : "#9467bd","text":"CORP"},
   { "x_axis":40, "y_axis": 110,"width":50,"height":20,"color": "#8c564b","text":"TAX"},
   { "x_axis":40, "y_axis": 130,"width":50,"height":20,"color" : "#e377c2","text":"REUTERS ALL"}
]
```

Comment: What is the `data` you are passing to this function? Can you create a standalone example of `jsfiddle` and reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select the same kind of element when using D3's data pattern to tell it what to match the data with. That is, you should run

```
rectangle = svg.selectAll("rect").data(data).enter().append("rect");
```

This will tell D3 to look for `rect` elements (`.selectAll("rect")`), match `data` to them (`.data(data)`), and append new `rect` elements for those that haven't been matched (`.enter().append("rect")`).

Your current code doesn't allow D3 to match up data and elements properly, as you're passing the wrong thing to `.selectAll()`. You need to make the same change for the `text` elements later on.

In addition, you're always appending new SVGs in your `CreateLegend` function and then using those to set up the legend. This means that new legends will be added every time you call the function regardless of what's already there. You can easily fix this by moving the code that creates the SVGs outside the function.

Complete example [here](http://vida.io/documents/GX5zokXXnCtta8tx6).

Comment: I did the same but it is appending the rectangles. I modified the code  as rectangle= svg.selectAll("rect").data(data).enter().append("rect");
 instead of rectangle= svg.selectAll(div).data(data).enter().append("rect");

Comment: Updated the answer. Just create the SVGs outside the function.